# Добавление элементов DevExpress в панель элементов

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, devexpress

Я установил на ПК DevExpress, теперь нужно добавить его элементы на панель элементов, чего не могу сделать. В интернете не смог найти решения, так что решил сам задать вопрос. Как добавить элементы управления DevExpress в Панель элементов Visual Studio?

Comment: Автоматом должны появляться. Если нет, то попробуйте пункт меню «DevExpress -> Repair Toolbox»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первым делом убедитесь, что вы используете версию, которая поддерживает выбранную вами версию Visual Studio и .NET Framework - https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/8092/Prerequisites Часто проблема возникает именно на этом этапе.

Если это не помогает, попробуйте Repair Toolbox как посоветовали в комментариях. 
Так же есть смысл глянуть лог инсталляции на наличие ошибок. Если они есть, но они не наводят на мысль что могло пойти не так, или Repair Toolbox так же не помог - обратитесь в отдел поддержки devexpress.com/ask и прикрепите имеющиеся логи